# Updating Theme from project in Flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm working on a project where we have a main project that uses another project as it's theme. Everything is great when we manually update the theme through 
Project -> Properties -> Flex Theme.
My / Our problem is that when our automatic build system recompiles the solution, the Theme doesn't get updated.

Currently we are doing the following: 
Recompiling the theme project.
Copying the SWC on top of the current theme SWC and then recompiling the main project, but it's still not working.

Anyone able to help?

Updated:
We are using a build.bat file that is run everytime containing the following:
 - A build.xml file that specifies the various projects we use.
 - A build.bat file that executes the build

Build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="main">   
    <target name="theme">
        <fb.exportReleaseBuild project="theme" destdir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target name="main">
        <fb.exportReleaseBuild project="Main project" destdir="bin-output"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Build.bat: **(Only the part concerning Theme and the main project**

```
echo **building theme**
%FLASHBUILDER_GUI% --launcher.suppressErrors -noSplash -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -data "%WORKSPACE%" -file "%BUILDXML%" theme
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto theme_ok
if %errorlevel% == 13 goto theme_ok rem Seems to happen after a successful build
echo Failed to build, error code %errorlevel%
exit /b %errorlevel%

:theme_ok
echo copying theme
if not exist "%appdata%\Adobe" mkdir "%appdata%\Adobe"
if not exist "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder" mkdir "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder"
if not exist "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder\Themes" mkdir "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder\Themes"
if not exist "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder\Themes\theme" mkdir "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder\Themes\theme"
copy ..\theme\bin\theme.swc "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Builder\Themes\theme"
:theme_copy_ok

echo **Building Main Project**
%FLASHBUILDER% --launcher.suppressErrors -noSplash -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -data "%WORKSPACE%" -file "%BUILDXML%" main
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Can you provide ANT target here with all dependencies.

Comment: I wouldn't use Flash Builder personally, and second, have you tried to do a clean/rebuild?  I could be that FB doesn't "see" the swc change, hence it doesn't actually recompile the project.

Comment: @Varun Bajaj, I have updated my post with the Ant target.

Comment: @J_A_X, I have tried that and what would you recommend instead of Flash Builder for building?

Comment: I'm a big fan of IntelliJ as an IDE, but I normally try to create a maven script for my Flex projects so that my build process is not IDE specific and can be built from the continuous integration server.